# Wrong input field is removed by button click

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with some jQuery code I've written.

It seems that the input field on **Page 2** is being deleted by a button meant to remove input fields on **Page 1**. How can I go about sorting this out? Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/psL2s/) on jsFiddle - try adding new input fields on **Page 2** and then using the remove button on **Page 1**. Funnily enough it seems to not work the other way around. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_roomFac').click(function () {
        var $objs = $('select[name*=roomFac]');
        var n = $objs.size() + 1;
        var $obj = $objs.first().clone();
        $obj.attr('name', 'roomFac' + n).attr('id', 'roomFac' + n);
        $obj.appendTo($('#search_fac'));
    });

    $('#remove_roomFac').click(function () {
        var $objs = $('select[name*=roomFac]');
        if ($objs.size() > 1) {
            $objs.last().remove();
        }
    });

    $('#addFac').click(function () {
        var $objs = $('select[name*=request_roomFac]');
        var n = $objs.size() + 1;
        var $obj = $objs.first().clone();
        $obj.attr('name', 'request_roomFac' + n).attr('id', 'research_roomFac' + n);
        $obj.appendTo($('#request_fac'));
    });
    $('#removeFac').click(function () {
        var $objs = $('select[name*=request_roomFac]');
        if ($objs.size() > 1) {
            $objs.last().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use ('select[name*=roomFac]'); you select both drop downs because you are using contains selector. Try using the starts with selector ('select[name^=roomFac]');

[http://jsfiddle.net/eyecode/psL2s/2/][1]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have more context with your selectors to target the elements properly:

```
$('#remove_roomFac').click(function () {
    var $objs = $('#search_fac select[name*=roomFac]');
    if ($objs.size() > 1) {
        $objs.last().remove();
    }
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$('#removeFac').click(function () {
    var $objs = $('#request_fac select[name*=request_roomFac]');
    if ($objs.size() > 1) {
        $objs.last().remove();
    }
});
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ema59/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a div per page to scope your selectors relative to the clicked element.  $(this) is the button clicked, .closest then goes up to find the parent page, and then dives back down to find the select box on that page:

http://jsfiddle.net/psL2s/11/

```
$('#remove_roomFac').click(function () {
    var $objs = $(this).closest('.page').find('select[name*=roomFac] option');
    if ($objs.size() > 1) {
        $objs.last().remove();
    }
});
```

You could change the event to so that it works for both buttons and put this class on the button:
`$('.remove_option').click(function () {`

This allows you to create behavior by just adding classes to your elements, instead of hardcoding ID's in your JS.